# Existence of solution for a non-linear SDE

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

Since $\exp(\cdot)$ is locally Lipschitz, the following SDE has a strong solution:
$$
\mathrm{d}X_s=\exp(X_s) \, \mathrm{d}B_s,\quad X_0=1,
$$
where $B$ is a standard Brownian motion. I wonder if the following expression holds:
$$\mathbb{E}\int_0^T\exp(2X_s) \, \mathrm d s<\infty.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us show that
\begin{equation*}
    E\int_0^T e^{2X_t}\,dt=\infty \quad\text{for real }T\ge T_*:=e^{-2}/2. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}

Indeed, letting $Y_t:=e^{2X_t}$, we have
$Y_0=e^2$ and, by [Itô's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma#Mathematical_formulation_of_It%C3%B4%27s_lemma), for real $t\ge0$
\begin{equation*}
    dY_t=2e^{4X_t}dt+2e^{3X_t}dB_t= 2Y_t^2dt+2e^{3X_t}dB_t. 
\end{equation*}
So, for real $t$ and $u$ such that $0\le t\le u$ and $m(t):=EY_t$ we have $m(0)=e^2$ and
\begin{equation*}
    m(u)-m(t)=2\int_t^u EY_s^2ds\ge2\int_t^u m(s)^2ds.  
\end{equation*}
So, on any interval $[0,T)$ where the function $m$ is finite, $m\ge m(0)=e^2>0$ and $m$ is a  continuous increasing function. Moreover, then for any $t\in[0,T)$
\begin{equation*}
    m'_+(t):=\liminf_{u\downarrow t}\frac{m(u)-m(t)}{u-t}\ge 2m(t)^2. 
\end{equation*}
So, for $h:=-1/m$ and any $t\in[0,T)$
\begin{equation*}
    h'_+(t)=\liminf_{u\downarrow t}\frac{h(u)-h(t)}{u-t}
    =\liminf_{u\downarrow t}\frac{m(u)-m(t)}{u-t}\frac1{m(u)m(t)}\ge2. 
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
    0>h(T)\ge h(0)+2T=-e^{-2}+2T,
\end{equation*}
whence $T<T_*$. So, if $T\ge T_*$, then the increasing function $m$ is not finite on $[0,T)$. So, $m(t)=EY_t=Ee^{2X_t}=\infty$ for all $t$ in a left neighborhood of $T$ if $T\ge T_*$. So, we get \eqref{1}.
$\quad\Box$

Comment: The sixth row uses $\mathbb E \int_t^u \exp(6X(s))<\infty$?

Comment: @ShengWang : Why? According to the definition of the stochastic integral and as in the proof of Itô's lemma, you first work locally, with finite stopping times $T_n$ such $T_n\to\infty$ a.s., providing for the finiteness of the truncated integrals, and then use the condition $T_n\to\infty$ to get what is written in the 6th line.

Comment: I got it, thanks!